# How to get the base path in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, url, path, location, href

`window.location`works fine, but returns me the whole, absolute path, like `http://domain.xyz/punch/lines`. But I only need `http://domain.xyz/`. How can I extract only that first part? And how can I make that dynamic, I mean to be always the same even when the subdirectory path gets longer?

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You can get the protocol and the host separately, and then join them to get what you need

```
window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/"
```

As a sidenote, `window.location.pathname` would contain the path.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but is it supported in most browsers like firefox (i have checked it), chrome, ie (8,9,10) and safari?

Comment: @NullPointer - Should be supported in all browsers

Answer (score 29):

You can use this statement

```
var baseUrl = document.location.origin;
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
location.protocol + "//" + location.host
```

Comment: I agree. Make this a comment.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but is it supported in most browsers like firefox (i have checked it), chrome, ie (8,9,10) and safari?

Answer (score 2):

I think it will ok for you

```
var base_url = window.location.origin;

var host = window.location.host;

var pathArray = window.location.pathname.split( '/' );
```