# How to get base url with jquery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In joomla php there I can use `$this->baseurl` to get the base path, but I wanted to get the base path in jquery.

The base path may be any of the following example:

```
http://www.example.com/
http://localhost/example
http://www.example.com/sub/example
```

The `example` may also change.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the base path in jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17992578/how-to-get-the-base-path-in-jquery)

Comment: @Mritunjay I already saw that, but in my case the base path is different as I wished to get the base path like in php we do in joomla

Comment: So, none of the answers solved your problem?

Comment: pick an answer, please?

Answer (score 294):

I think this will work well for you:

```
var base_url = window.location.origin;

var host = window.location.host;

var pathArray = window.location.pathname.split( '/' );
```

Comment: Nice short and sweet, thanks. `window.location.origin`

Comment: this should be the preferred answer, as it is short, concise, and works fine.

Comment: window.location.origin is not defined in ie9

Comment: @jnoreiga Who's still using ie9 ツ

Comment: I wish it were that simple @AlexandreDaubricourt

Comment: These do not work between localhost and a published solution.

Comment: what does this show in an iframe?

Answer (score 237):

This one will help you...

```
var getUrl = window.location;
var baseUrl = getUrl .protocol + "//" + getUrl.host + "/" + getUrl.pathname.split('/')[1];
```

Comment: Yes, it works!
`http://localhost/myapp/what/ever/sub/folder` -> getBaseUrl -> `http://localhost/myapp`
:-)

Comment: This won't work in all the cases, as indicated by somehow undervoted answer by @Artjom B. For example, when a site is tested over local network (and domain is substituted with IP + local path) the base url could be something like `192.168.0.23/~sites/site/html/` instead of `site.dev`. Getting the full pathname with Javascript is not an option too, because a site can have any number of virtual subdirectories.

Comment: best answer...works fine for me in ionic and react.js

Answer (score 42):

This will get base url

```
var baseurl = window.location.origin+window.location.pathname;
```

Comment: this is the same as window.location.href

Comment: it is not the same, pathname gives you the path segment of the url, href contains the query params as well

Answer (score 40):

`document.baseURI` returns base URL also respecting the value in `<base/>` tag
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/baseURI

Comment: This also returns the hashbang, which most probably not what the OP wanted

Comment: @Marcel That is NOT an issue so long as you set the <base> tag in the head of the document. This is the BEST answer on this page!

Answer (score 27):

This is an extremely old question, but here are the approaches I personally use ...

### Get Standard/Base URL

As many have already stated, this works for most situations.

```
var url = window.location.origin;
```

### Get Absolute Base URL

However, this simple approach can be used to strip off any port numbers.

```
var url = "http://" + location.host.split(":")[0];
```

**Edit:** To address the concern, posed by *Jason Rice*, the following can be used to automatically insert the correct protocol type ...

```
var url = window.location.protocol + "//" + location.host.split(":")[0];
```

### Set Base URL

As a bonus -- the base URL can then be redefined globally.

```
document.head.innerHTML = document.head.innerHTML + "<base href='" + url + "' />";
```

Comment: Unless your protocol is something other than http like https (then setting the url protocol to "http://" will present some really weird errors depending on how you want to use the url).

Answer (score 23):

the easiest way to get base url in JavaScript

```
window.location.origin
```

Comment: This is actually not jQuery. jQuery looks like this: $(location).attr("origin");

Answer (score 14):

This is not possible from javascript, because this is a server-side property. Javascript on the client cannot know where joomla is installed. The best option is to somehow include the value of `$this->baseurl` into the page javascript and then use this value (`phpBaseUrl`).

You can then build the url like this:

```
var loc = window.location;
var baseUrl = loc.protocol + "//" + loc.hostname + (loc.port? ":"+loc.port : "") + "/" + phpBaseUrl;
```

Comment: Note that `loc.host` has the port, for an url like `http://localhost:8082/` this method will produce `http://localhost:8082:8082/`, `window.location.hostname` should be used instead.

Comment: @TiberiuC. Thanks, added.

Answer (score 9):

```
var getUrl = window.location;
var baseurl = getUrl.origin; //or
var baseurl =  getUrl.origin + '/' +getUrl.pathname.split('/')[1];
```

But you can't say that the baseurl() of CodeIgniter(or php joomla) will return the same value, as it is possible to change the baseurl in the .htaccess file of these frameworks.

For example :

If you have an .htaccess file like this in your localhost :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /CodeIgniter/
RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|resources|robots.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

The $this->baseurl() will return http://localhost/CodeIgniter/

Answer (score 8):

Had the same issue a while ago, my problem was, I simply needed the base url. There are a lot of detailed options here but to get around this, simply use the `window.location` object. ***Actually type this in the browser console and hit enter to select your options there. Well for my case it was simply:***

```
window.location.origin
```

Answer (score 5):

I've run into this need on several Joomla project.  The simplest way I've found to address is to add a hidden input field to my template:

```
<input type="hidden" id="baseurl" name="baseurl" value="<?php echo $this->baseurl; ?>" />
```

When I need the value in JavaScript:

```
var baseurl = document.getElementById('baseurl').value;
```

Not as fancy as using pure JavaScript but simple and gets the job done.

Answer (score 5):

You can easily get it with:

```
var currentUrl = window.location.href;
```

or, if you want the original URL, use:

```
var originalUrl = window.location.origin;
```

Comment: What's the difference?

Answer (score 4):

The format is hostname/pathname/search

So the url is :

```
var url = window.location.hostname + window.location.pathname + window.location.hash
```

For your case

```
window.location.hostname = "stackoverflow.com"
window.location.pathname ="/questions/25203124/how-to-get-base-url-with-jquery-or-javascript"
window.location.hash = ""
```

So basically the baseurl = hostname = window.location.hostname

Answer (score 4):

I am surprised that non of the answers consider the base url if it was set in `<base>` tag. All current answers try to get the host name or server name or first part of address. This is the complete logic which also considers the `<base>` tag (which may refer to another domain or protocol):

```
function getBaseURL(){
  var elem=document.getElementsByTagName("base")[0];
  if (typeof(elem) != 'undefined' && elem != null){
     return elem.href;
  }
  return window.location.origin;
}
```

Jquery format:

```
function getBaseURL(){
  if ($("base").length){
     return $("base").attr("href");
  }
  return window.location.origin;
}
```

Without getting involved with the logic above, the shorthand solution which considers both `<base>` tag and `window.location.origin`:

Js:

```
var a=document.createElement("a");
a.href=".";
var baseURL= a.href;
```

Jquery:

```
var baseURL= $('<a href=".">')[0].href
```

**Final note:** for a local file in your computer (not on a host) the `window.location.origin` only returns the `file://` but the sorthand solution above returns the complete correct path.

Comment: This is not the best way.  Also, see @DaniilSamoylov's answer, which does incorporate the `<base>` element.

Comment: baseURI returns the base URL of a node so in this case it returns the base path + document name. you will need more codes to remove the document name from that URL. @Brad

Comment: This solution does _not_ give back the correct base URL when the root directory of the web page is within a sub directory (e.g. http://www.example.com/appRoot/). It only works when the root dir of the webpage is directly located on the webhost's root.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a short one:

```js
const base = new URL('/', location.href).href;

console.log(base);
```

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend for everyone to create HTML base tag in development, then assign the href dynamically, so in production whatever host a client uses, it will automacically addapt to it:

```
<html>
 <title>Some page title</titile>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var head  = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var base = document.createElement("base");
    base.href = window.document.location.origin;
    head.appendChild(base);
  </script>
 </head>
 ...
```

So if you are in localhot:8080, you will reach every linked or referenced file from the base, eg: `http://localhost:8080/some/path/file.html`
If you are in www.example.com, it will be `http://www.example.com/some/path/file.html`

Also note that, every location you're on, you should not use references like globs in hrefs, eg: Parent location causes `http://localhost:8080/` not `http://localhost:8080/some/path/`.

Pretent you reference all hyperlinks as full sentenced without the bas url.

Answer (score 2):

```
window.location.origin+"/"+window.location.pathname.split('/')[1]+"/"+page+"/"+page+"_list.jsp"
```

almost same as Jenish answer but a little shorter.

Answer (score 2):

I was just on the same stage and this solution works for me

In the view

```
<?php
    $document = JFactory::getDocument();

    $document->addScriptDeclaration('var base = \''.JURI::base().'\'');
    $document->addScript('components/com_name/js/filter.js');
?>
```

In js file you access `base` as a variable for example in your scenario:

```
console.log(base) // will print
// http://www.example.com/
// http://localhost/example
// http://www.example.com/sub/example
```

I do not remember where I take this information to give credit, if I find it I will edit the answer

Answer (score 2):

A simpler answer is here, `window.location.href = window.location.origin;`

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Easy

```
$('<img src=>')[0].src
```

Generates a img with empty src-name forces the browser to calculate the base-url by itself, no matter if you have `/index.html` or anything else.

Comment: This seems the most elegant solution of all and the only one that doesn't duplicate browser logic, which is nice. I do wonder how portable it is. Is there anything in the HTML specs that would suggest this is guaranteed to work in all browsers?

Comment: @MatthijsKooijman Depends on interpretation of html specs. If you say a filename of length 0 is a valid resource-name ... it does match all browsers.

Comment: Understand how browsers are made. You have a couple of programmers, the (indirect) wish to built a browser. Their first source is the html-specs. They read the specs and this is one of the questions they realy like to solve. How would you think they (all) decide on this circumstances?

Comment: This should be the selected answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's something quick that also works with `file://` URLs.

I came up with this one-liner:

```
[((1!=location.href.split(location.href.split("/").pop())[0].length?location.href.split(location.href.split("/").pop())[0]:(location.protocol,location.protocol+"//" + location.host+"/"))).replace(location.protocol+"//"+location.protocol+"//"+location.protocol+"://")]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var getUrl = window.location;
var baseUrl = getUrl .protocol + "//" + getUrl.host + "/" + getUrl.pathname.split('/')[1];
```

Comment: Please consider adding a description to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that the `example.com` may change so I suspect that actually you need the base url just to be able to use relative path notation for your scripts. In this particular case there is no need to use scripting - instead add the base tag to your header:

```
<head>
  <base href="http://www.example.com/">
</head>
```

I usually generate the link via PHP.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone would like to see this broken out into a very robust function

```
    function getBaseURL() {
        var loc = window.location;
        var baseURL = loc.protocol + "//" + loc.hostname;
        if (typeof loc.port !== "undefined" && loc.port !== "") baseURL += ":" + loc.port;
        // strip leading /
        var pathname = loc.pathname;
        if (pathname.length > 0 && pathname.substr(0,1) === "/") pathname = pathname.substr(1, pathname.length - 1);
        var pathParts = pathname.split("/");
        if (pathParts.length > 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i < pathParts.length; i++) {
                if (pathParts[i] !== "") baseURL += "/" + pathParts[i];
            }
        }
        return baseURL;
    }
```

Comment: This just gives the whole url.  Not a base URL.

Comment: indeed, not sure where I was going with that.  I have long since switched to setting that with server-side code

Answer (score -1):

Split and join the URL:

```
const s = 'http://free-proxy.cz/en/abc'
console.log(s.split('/').slice(0,3).join('/'))
```

Answer (score -2):

Getting the base url
|Calls controller from js

```
function getURL() {

var windowurl = window.location.href;
var baseUrl = windowurl.split('://')[1].split('/')[0]; //split function

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url='http://'+baseUrl+'/url from controller';
xhr.open("GET", url);
xhr.send(); //object use to send

xhr.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if(xhr.readyState==4 && this.status==200){
 //console.log(xhr.responseText); //the response of the request
        
 document.getElementById("id from where you called the function").innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
}
  }
}
```

Answer (score -5):

Put this in your header, so it will be available whenever you need it.

```
var base_url = "<?php echo base_url();?>";
```

You will get `http://localhost:81/your-path-file` or `http://localhost/your-path-file`.