# Javascript redirect to hash from base url

Tags: javascript, html

The following is not working (I just get a reload):

```
            location.host += "/#settings";
            location.reload();
```

How do I tell JS to navigate to a URL based on the existing url and totally reload that page (not just append the hash)?

This also does not work:

```
             window.location.href = "/#settings";
```

My base url is `"http://localhost:sss/pricing"`

I want to redirect to `"http://localhost:sss/#settings"` with a reload.

I don't want to type `localhost` anywhere.

Even this gives me `settings#lol`:

```
            var desiredBase = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + "/";
            var path = '#lol';
            window.location.href = desiredBase + path;
            location.reload();
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226714/how-to-get-browser-to-navigate-to-url-in-javascript

Comment: @vso no, that doesn't work with the hash.

Comment: `window.location.href = "#settings"`; ?

Comment: `and totally reload that page` @nocodename

Comment: Hey, try the function they wrote here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25203124/how-to-get-base-url-with-jquery-or-javascript

Comment: @VSO I can get the base url just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another edit, stole base url code from here: [How to get base url with jquery or javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25203124/how-to-get-base-url-with-jquery-or-javascript)

```
<html>

  <body>
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <script>
      (function(){
        var getUrl = window.location;
        var desiredBase = getUrl.protocol + "//" + getUrl.host + "/" + getUrl.pathname.split('/')[1];
        var path = `#lol`;      
        window.location.href = desiredBase + path; 
        location.reload();
      })();
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

This *is* reloading the page locally after appending. Try it.

Edit: I see the issue with not getting the base url with href, working on it, hold on.

Comment: You're making an assumption that I want to set my base url in code - I don't.

Comment: @SB2055 All good, didn't assume that you did. Maybe the other guy thinks I downvoted him. I am not sure I am following. Do you want to detect current url and append #whatever to it?

Comment: Thanks for continuing to help.  I've updated the question with an example where this doesn't work.

Comment: @SB2055: Try that after the edit, seems to be working for me.

Comment: Updated question again with what happens when I try this.

Comment: @SB2055 The risks of assumptions... ;)

Comment: @spender get a life ;)

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
location.href += "/#settings";
location.reload();
```

Answer (score -2):

You can try something like this :

`location.hash = "settings";`

This sets part after "#" in the URL

then do: `location.reload();` and it should fix the issue

Let me know if it works

Thanks